# Printing string pointed to from Register in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I have a string being moved and i want to print it based on the register.

I did the following:

```
gdb x $esp
0xbffff110:  "\274\205\004\b\324\361\377\277\334\361\377\277]\257\344\267\304s\374\267"

{then I copied the address}

>> x *0xbffff110
0x80485bc <__dso_handle+12>:     "test1"
```

Is there any way to do this in one step?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this in one step?

```
 (gdb) print *(char**)$esp
```

Comment: If the register is a pointer then this works: `print (char*)$rdi`